# Why can't I execute truncate and grant statement on a table in parallel?

Tags: postgresql, concurrentmodification

My use case is that I need to execute `GRANT` and `TRUNCATE` statements on a table concurrently.

**Sample scenario:**

When I try to execute below statements in parallel(two separate terminals):

```
while true; do psql -U <user> -d <database> -c 'GRANT select ON test1 TO <user>;'; done

while true; do psql -U <user> -d <database> -c 'TRUNCATE test1;'; done
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  tuple concurrently updated
```

I don't understand the reason for the error. The `TRUNCATE` statement doesn't have anything to do with privileges. Then why can't I execute these statements concurrently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concurrent update that PostgreSQL is complaining about is not an update to the table `test1`, but to the catalog table `pg_class`.

Both `GRANT` and `TRUNCATE` have to update the table's row in `pg_class`, one to change `relacl` and the other to change `relfilenode`.

Now while updates to normal tables are protected by locks, that is not the case for catalog updates. They use some kind of “optimistic locking” where all but the first concurrent modification will cause this error.

Now you may call this a bug, but I'd say that if you have enough concurrent `GRANT` and `TRUNCATE` statements in your application that this becomes a problem, there's something wrong with the application.

You may find [this e-mail](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3473.1393693757%40sss.pgh.pa.us) of Tom Lane on the subject enlightening.